# Django: cannot import CSS file from static

Tags: python, html, css, django, templates

### Django returns 404 error code in terminal logs while trying to import style.css file

Hi, I have problem with loading static files. Error occurred in my main HTML file (frame.html - base for other files). I made everything for correct work of static files, here's all of the applications (code, images) to my problem:

File system:

```
├── jdn
   ├── __init__.py
   ├── asgi.py
   ├── settings.py
   ├── urls.py
   └── wsgi.py
├── main
   ├── __init__.py
   ├── admin.py
   ├── apps.py
   ├── forms.py
   ├── models.py
   ├── pdf.py
   ├── templates
      └── main
          ├── create.html
          ├── frame.html
          ├── main.html
          ├── minauth.html
          ├── report.html
          ├── searchinit.html
          ├── searchres.html
          ├── univerauth.html
          └── viewuser.html
   ├── tests.py
   ├── urls.py
   └── views.py
├── manage.py
├── media
   └── main
      ...
└── static
  ├── admin
    ├── css
      ...
  └── main
    └── css
      └── style.css
```

urls.py(core):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

urls.py(app):

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.main, name='main'),
    path('token/', views.get_token, name='get_token'),
    path('create/', views.create_user, name='create_user'),
    path('search/', views.search_user, name='search_user'),
    path('token_report/', views.get_min_tok, name='get_min_tok'),
    path('report/', views.view_report, name='view_report'),
    path('view/<int:id>', views.view_user, name='view_user')
]
```

settings.py:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path


BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-##=mjtuei4ry@#t5+(!)$fd@v=7_ubr-w#%1(0#$%ed$i$nus!'


DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main.apps.MainConfig',
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'jdn.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'jdn.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'jdndb',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-ru'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Bishkek'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',

)


DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

MEDIA_URL = "media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
```

frame.html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Единое окно</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../media/main/win.png" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='{% static "main/css/style.css" %}'>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

#### So, don't understand what's the problem here, Will be very thankful for anybody's help

Comment: Change `STATIC_ROOT` and `MEDIA_ROOT` to `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')` and `MEDIA_ROOT` to `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')`

Comment: I tried, didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='{% static "./main/css/style.css" %}'>
```

try this and tell

Comment: I would like to access by web url or in another case I wouldn't use static tag, but thanks for help in solving the problem